# bash user input if

Tags: bash, user-input

I am trying to do a simple question in bash:

```
Do you want to do that? [Y,n] _
```

Tried

```
echo "Do that? [Y,n]"
read DO_THAT
if ["DO_THAT"="y"]; then
  do_that
fi
```

but it fails: `bash: [y=y]: command not found`

what am I doing wrong??!

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You might consider explicit prompting: -p and specifying 1-character-input -n1 which allows to insert y without ENTER.

```
read -n1 -p "Do that? [y,n]" doit 
case $doit in  
  y|Y) echo yes ;; 
  n|N) echo no ;; 
  *) echo dont know ;; 
esac
```

Comment: Nice! +1 I didn't know you could prompt for one letter without pressing enter like that :)

Comment: If you have a "don't know" case, is there any way to go back to the "Do that?" prompt again?

Comment: @ekaj: Not as an option for read or case. You might surround it with a loop or put it in a function and call that function recursively, to enforce a matching answer.

Comment: @cutrightjm: Another alternative is using the select keyword, but then you select by number and get prompted for a valid input, but then you have to press ENTER to terminate your input.

Answer (score 20):

```
echo "Do that? [Y,n]"
read input
if [[ $input == "Y" || $input == "y" ]]; then
        echo "do that"
else
        echo "don't do that"
fi
```

Pay close attention to the syntax and spacing of the if conditional, it gets me all the time in bash :)

Comment: [This is _very_ late but] technically, you've indicated that `Y` is the default option, but your logic will actually "not do that" if the input is anything other than `Y` or `y`. To make your echo clearer, your should say `"Do that? [y/N]"` or your if statement should change to check for the `n`/`N` characters. +1 because your answer is simpler! :)

Answer (score 6):

Look up the options to `read` in bash - you can do the prompting etc.

```
read -p "Do that? [Y,n]" -i Y input
```

For the rest, leave spaces around command names ('[' is a command - you might even find it in `/bin/[` though it is also a shell built-in) and arguments.

---

Bash Manual, Chapter 4: Shell Builtin Commands

> read
>
> ```
>   read [-ers] [-a aname] [-d delim] [-i text] [-n nchars] [-N nchars]  
>        [-p prompt] [-t timeout] [-u fd] [name ...]
> ```
>
> One line is read from the standard input, or from the file descriptor fd supplied
>   as an argument to the ‘-u’ option, and the first word is assigned to the first
>   name, the second word to the second name, and so on, with leftover words and
>   their intervening separators assigned to the last name. If there are fewer words
>   read from the input stream than names, the remaining names are assigned
>   empty values. The characters in the value of the IFS variable are used to split
>   the line into words. The backslash character ‘\’ may be used to remove any
>   special meaning for the next character read and for line continuation. If no
>   names are supplied, the line read is assigned to the variable REPLY. The return
>   code is zero, unless end-of-file is encountered, read times out (in which case the
>   return code is greater than 128), or an invalid file descriptor is supplied as the
>   argument to ‘-u’.
>
> Options, if supplied, have the following meanings:
>
> -a aname The words are assigned to sequential indices of the array variable
>   aname, starting at 0. All elements are removed from aname before
>   the assignment. Other name arguments are ignored.
>
> -d delim The first character of delim is used to terminate the input line,
>   rather than newline.
>   -e Readline (see Chapter 8 [Command Line Editing], page 93) is used
>   to obtain the line. Readline uses the current (or default, if line
>   editing was not previously active) editing settings.
>   -i text If Readline is being used to read the line, text is placed into the
>   editing buffer before editing begins.
>
> -n nchars read returns after reading nchars characters rather than waiting
>   for a complete line of input, but honor a delimiter if fewer than
>   nchars characters are read before the delimiter.
>
> -N nchars read returns after reading exactly nchars characters rather than
>   waiting for a complete line of input, unless EOF is encountered or
>   read times out. Delimiter characters encountered in the input are
>   not treated specially and do not cause read to return until nchars
>   characters are read.
>
> -p prompt Display prompt, without a trailing newline, before attempting to
>   read any input. The prompt is displayed only if input is coming
>   from a terminal.
>
> -r If this option is given, backslash does not act as an escape character.
>   The backslash is considered to be part of the line. In particular, a
>   backslash-newline pair may not be used as a line continuation.
>
> -s Silent mode. If input is coming from a terminal, characters are not
>   echoed.
>
> -t timeout
>   Cause read to time out and return failure if a complete line of input
>   is not read within timeout seconds. timeout may be a decimal
>   number with a fractional portion following the decimal point. This
>   option is only effective if read is reading input from a terminal,
>   pipe, or other special file; it has no effect when reading from regular
>   files. If timeout is 0, read returns success if input is available on
>   the specified file descriptor, failure otherwise. The exit status is
>   greater than 128 if the timeout is exceeded.
>
> -u fd Read input from file descriptor fd.

Answer (score 4):

You need to put a blank Space between "if" and the variable:

`if [  $var == "y"  ]; then
      echo "ese era el problema"
fi`

Answer (score 2):

You can use case modification operator:

```
if [ "${DECISION^^}" = "Y" ]; then
...
fi
```

You can find more in bash manual under "Parameter Expansion".