# Script to read user input not running when run with sh interpreter

Tags: bash, shell

This may be a duplicate of [bash user input if](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5542016/bash-user-input-if), but the answers do not solved my problem, so I think there is something else.

I have the next script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Do that? [Y,n]"
read input
if [[ $input == "Y" || $input == "y" ]]; then
        echo "do that"
else
        echo "don't do that"
fi
```

and when I do `sh basic-if.sh`

[image]

Also I have

```
#!/bin/bash

read -n1 -p "Do that? [y,n]" doit 
case $doit in  
  y|Y) echo yes ;; 
  n|N) echo no ;; 
  *) echo dont know ;; 
esac
```

and when I do `sh basic-if2.sh`

[image]

I think my bash has a problem because appereatly the other users didn't have these problems running those examples. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running the script with `sh scriptname` overrides any default interpreter set inside your script. In your case the bourne shell (`sh`) runs the script instead of the bourne again shell (`bash`). The `sh` does not support `[[` and the `read` command in its POSIX compliant form does not support `-n` flag.

In all likelihood, your `sh` in your system is not symlinked to `bash` and it is operating in itself as a POSIX compliant shell. Fix the problem by running

```
bash basic-if2.sh
```

or run it with a `./` before the script name there by making the system to look out for the interpreter in the first line of the file (`#!/bin/bash`). Instead of fixing the interpreter you could also do `#!/usr/bin/env bash` for the OS to look up where `bash` is installed and execute with that.

```
chmod a+x basic-if2.sh
./basic-if2.sh
```

You could additionally see if `ls -lrth /bin/sh` to see if its symlinked to `dash` which is a minimal POSIX compliant shell available on Debian systems.

Comment: Oh, that fixed the problem, but now it created another, the change of color in the fonts  `\e[31m Example \e[0m` are not recognized

Comment: @Delfin: I don't see them in your script above? How are you printing those colors?

Comment: I didn't place it for the minimum working example. But I am doing it this way:  `echo "\e[31m Example \e[0m"`

Comment: @Delfin: It is because `echo` does not recognize ANSI color codes by default without doing `echo -e`. But the latter is not portable in POSIX systems. Recommend using `printf '\e[31m Example \e[0m\n'`